# Next-Auth slow server response time when using server session

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm currently trying to set up next-auth (auth.js) with it's current beta version. (Tried both the stable and the beta version, same problem occurs). When i have a session argument that checks in my root layout.js if we are logged in or not and based on that show a navbar i get a significant increase in initial response time from the server (frontend hosted on vercel). Sometimes up to 2 seconds. (1.2 Second average). Without that navbar argument my site loads instantly (100-300ms).
I went as far as using my own login page and the login page that auth-js provides but nothing improved the situation. I even activated edge in the options with zero difference in that initial response time.

I already seperated my frontpage so that new users won't be effected by this.
I used the example that next-auth provides to render my navbar using the server session:
[example](https://next-auth-example.vercel.app/server-example)

The only major difference i see is that i am using JWT tokens and my own backend (without storing anything on the server) but thats it. Anyone have an idea why i might be getting such a bad response time from the server? Here is my code:

layout.js

```
export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <ThemeRegistry>
        <Navbar />
            {children}
        </ThemeRegistry>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

navbar.js

```
import NavLoggedIn from './NavLoggedIn';
import { auth } from "@/auth"

export default async function Navbar() {

  const session = await auth()
  if (!session?.user) return <></>
  return (
      <NavLoggedIn />
  );
}
```

auth.js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import axios from "axios";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const BACKEND_ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME = 45 * 60;
const BACKEND_REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME = 6 * 24 * 60 * 60;

const getCurrentEpochTime = () => {
  return Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
};

const SIGN_IN_HANDLERS = {
  "google": async (user, account, profile, email, credentials) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: process.env.NEXTAUTH_BACKEND_URL + "dj-rest-auth/google/",
        data: {
          access_token: account["id_token"]
        },
      });
      account["meta"] = response.data;
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return false;
    }
  }
};
const SIGN_IN_PROVIDERS = Object.keys(SIGN_IN_HANDLERS);

export const config = {
  secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: BACKEND_REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME,
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        authorization: {
          params: {
            prompt: "consent",
            access_type: "offline",
            response_type: "code"
          }
        }
      }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({user, account, profile, email, credentials}) {
      if (!SIGN_IN_PROVIDERS.includes(account.provider)) return false;
      return SIGN_IN_HANDLERS[account.provider](
        user, account, profile, email, credentials
      );
    },
    async jwt({user, token, account}) {

      if (user && account) {
        let backendResponse = account.provider === "credentials" ? user : account.meta;
        token["user"] = backendResponse.user;
        token["access_token"] = backendResponse.access;
        token["refresh_token"] = backendResponse.refresh;
        token["ref"] = getCurrentEpochTime() + BACKEND_ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME;
        return token;
      }

      if (getCurrentEpochTime() > token["ref"]) {
        const response = await axios({
          method: "post",
          url: process.env.NEXTAUTH_BACKEND_URL + "/token/refresh/",
          data: {
            refresh: token["refresh_token"],
          },
        });
        token["access_token"] = response.data.access;
        token["refresh_token"] = response.data.refresh;
        token["ref"] = getCurrentEpochTime() + BACKEND_ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME;
      }
      return token;
    },

    async session({token}) {
      return token;
    },
  }
};



export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth(config)
```